# Targeting the child elements of the current div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a 5 star rating control that is setup like so:

```
     $('.Star-Rating-Block').each(function() {
        $('.star-rating').hover(
          // Handles the mouseover
          function() {
              $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('star-hover');
          },
          // Handles the mouseout
          function() {
              $(this).prevAll().andSelf().removeClass('star-hover');
          }
        ).click(function() {
           $('.star-rating').removeClass('star-select'); // Removes the selected class from all of them
           $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('star-select').removeClass('star-hover'); // Adds the selected class to just the one you clicked

           var rating = $(this).data('Star-Rating-Block');
        });
      });
```

Unfortunately, there are 3 separate .Star-Rating-Block divs, each containing five images with the .star-rating class. I am trying to figure out how to target the specific children of whichever is the currently active .Star-Rating-Block. I want to make it so that users can using any of the 3 rating controls without the others being affected. I feel like I'm close to finishing the function but I'm not sure on what to do to finalize it. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you give a JS Fiddle?

Comment: `$(i).prevAll().andSelf()` what is `i`?

Comment: And why assign a value to `rating` if you don't use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the current block as a variable and use as context:

```
$('.Star-Rating-Block').each(function() {
        var container = this;
        $('.star-rating', container).hover(
          // Handles the mouseover
          function() {
              $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('star-hover');
          },
          // Handles the mouseout
          function() {
              $(this).prevAll().andSelf().removeClass('star-hover');
          }
        ).click(function() {
           $('.star-rating', container).removeClass('star-select'); // Removes the selected class from all of them
           $(i).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('star-select').removeClass('star-hover'); // Adds the selected class to just the one you clicked

           var rating = $(this).data('Star-Rating-Block');
        });
      });
```

Note sure about the `$(i)` since you haven't defined `i` anywhere...

However, the `each` is not needed:

```
$('.Star-Rating-Block .star-rating').hover(
  // Handles the mouseover
  function() {
      $(this).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('star-hover');
  },
  // Handles the mouseout
  function() {
      $(this).prevAll().andSelf().removeClass('star-hover');
  }
).click(function() {
    var container = $(this).closest('.Star-Rating-Block');
    $('.star-rating', container).removeClass('star-select'); // Removes the selected class from all of them
    $(i).prevAll().andSelf().addClass('star-select').removeClass('star-hover'); // Adds the selected class to just the one you clicked

    var rating = $(this).data('Star-Rating-Block');
});
```

Still not sure about the `$(i)` or what the point of assigning a value to a local `rating` variable which is never used is?

Comment: That is what I needed. I was told to use .each but I was wondering if it was necessary. Apparently not. I have the code working now thanks to your suggestion! 

As for the "i" that was a type-o that I accidentally copied over. It should be "this."